# reCAPTCHA - to appear after press submit

Tags: recaptcha

I wanna use reCAPTCHA for my form. The user must fill the form and then press "Submit". After this, under the "Submit"-Button, reCAPTCHA should appear.

How I can do this?

Comment: Blend? What do you mean? Like a reCAPTCHA milkshake? Or did you mean appear?

Comment: be easier to put it before submit

Comment: Sorry, i meant "appear". :( Yes, after I click "Submit" reCAPTCHA should appear.

Comment: Do you want to have the captcha loaded but hidden, or to actually load it only on submit? For our curioursity, why do you want to do it this way? (Not that we're trying to talk you out of it - it's a perfectiy sensible question either way.)

Comment: I wana do this way because I find that reCAPTCHA take to much space. Well, a good point. I think it would be better if reCAPTCHA load on submit. Not loaded but hidden. What do you think guys? Which would be better?

Answer (score 1):

If I were to want something like this, I would probably preload the reCAPTCHA into a [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

I think a user might get confused by a Captcha just appearing seemingly at random on the page when they press a button, but having a dialog come up to confirm some information is not unusual.

Comment: From a UI standpoint, I agree - but what happens then? Do you post the captcha value back to the server with the main form as a whole page post? If so and it doesn't validate then what do you do then? Reshow the whole form and auto-pop-up the dialog with a new captcha? What if the server throws a validation error on the original form data? I don't think those cases work as well. If you wanted to check the captcha in place before submitting the original dialog you'd have to either post the whole form back to the server with jQuery first, then refresh if you get a success back from that, etc.

Comment: I'm thinking you'd have to post everything together (You'd have to do this or the CAPTCHA would be circumventable.)  Auto-pop the dialog only if there's an error in the captcha, but not the rest of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do what you wanted, so initially keep reCaptcha hidden and show it on submit.

So I've hidden it with CSS:

```
div[id*='g-recaptcha'] {display:none}
```

And then showed it with jQuery when someone starts to fill in the form, so on input field focus:

```
$(".YOUR_CLASS_WRAPPER input").focus(function() {
    $(".YOUR_CLASS_WRAPPER div[id*='g-recaptcha']").css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2021, Contact form 7 Users

If you are using contact form 7 then you need to change a little bit. I am using the  @Mike code here with little changes.

### Hiding the reCAPTCHA

The 'Contact form 7' wrapper class is `wpcf7-form-control-wrap` `recaptcha` (two classes) and it is on a `span` container, so you need to use the style like this. No spaces between two classes here.

```css
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.recaptcha {
    display:none;
}
```

### Click to show

Add `id:submit` to your submit button using the form-tag in the Contact Form 7 window.
And use the id here.

```
[submit id:submit "Submit"]
```

```jquery
$("#submit").focus(function() {
    $(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap.recaptcha").css("display","block");
});
```